# suPHP, Ubuntu, files getting downloaded in browser

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, suphp

Im running the following setup:
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit
Zpanelcp (zpanelcp.com, which seems to be down for the moment...)
Apache2
PHP5

Trying to add suPHP to my setup. After following this: http://www.debiantutorials.com/installing-suphp/ (I know its for Debian, but seems to work). After restarting Apache and reloading a site on the server in the browser it starts to download a file with content from my site. This instead of reloading the site.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to turn on the php5 module

```
a2enmod php5
```